# using signals in django application code suggestion

Tags: python, django

Hello everyone I want to do charts based on my models **the count of mail_items sent per countries** , in my model you will see  *Country_origine*

the idea is I want to do another model that has 2 columns ' *country* ' and ' *mail_items_count* ' then I want to make a signal  when new item saved to ' *mail_items* ' the signal will update the ' *country+mail_items_count* ' increase the ' *mail_items_count* ' by one ,

also I want to make a function to sum all counts in the ' *mail_item_count* '  column .

in my **views.py** I want to make a view that query all *countries* with their ratio : ( I have to make  a dictionary, I have to loop throw each object in the query , and take the country name as the key in the dictionary , and take the counter (integer) divided by the output of the sum function to calculate the ratio of each country , and append in the dictionnary ... to send the response with all coutries and ratio dictionnary)

**models.py**

```
class mail_items(models.Model):
        mail_item_fid = models.OneToOneField(Mail_item_Event,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        Event_code = models.OneToOneField(Mail_item_Event,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="mail_item_event_cd")
        office_Evt_cd = models.ForeignKey(Office,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='office_Ev')
        Date_Evt = models.DateTimeField()
        Country_origine = models.ForeignKey(Pays, on_delete=models.CASCADE ,related_name='paysOrigine')
        Country_destination = models.ForeignKey(Pays,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='paysDestination')
        Expediteur = models.ForeignKey(Client,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='expedi')
        Destinateur = models.ForeignKey(Client,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='destin')
```

sorry if it was so long ....

I am still quite beginner even searched a lot I couldn't make this possible , can you help me coding this part or send me links that could help me out coding it ?

Comment: Is it essential for you to create the new model or would it be acceptable to just get the stats from the existing `Pays`?

Comment: what would you suggest me ?

Comment: I would suggest using aggregation or annotation instead if you are just looking for a count of mail_items per Pays? If so I'll write an answer in this way rather than using signals

Comment: awesome , I would like to see your answer in this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that the other model is called `mail_item_count`, you can use `post_save` signal on `mail_items` model which will be fired when you save an object of `mail_items` and update the count there. For instance:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

@receiver(post_save, sender=mail_items)
def update_count(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    # get the object for the required country or create it if it doesn't exist
    count_object, _ = mail_item_count.objects.get_or_create(country=instance.Country_origine)
    count_object.count = count_object.count + 1
    count_object.save()
```

And as for getting sum for all the countries, you can do something like:

```
sum(instance.count for instance in mail_item_count.objects.all())
```

Comment: thank you that was helpful  could you advice me more about what should I do in this part ```count_object.count = count_object.count + 1``` *to increase the ' mail_items_count ' by one* ....

Comment: This line is increasing the value stored in the count field on the count_object by 1

Comment: Because it give me error like **unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'**

Comment: `count_object,created = mail_item_count.objects.get_or_create(country=instance.Pays_origine)                        
               if created: count_object.count = count_object.count + 1 count_object.save() `I had to use something like that

Comment: You are right, but you don't have to check for `if created`, I'll update the answer

Comment: but I got this error  **'mail_item_count' object has no attribute 'count'**  ... `count_object.count = count_object.count + 1`

Comment: Check the name of the field in your mail_item_count model

Answer (score 0):

Using annotation you could do this without creating an additional model. It would also reduce the overhead of implementing signals

You can do this directly in a view like this to get counts across all countries:

```
from django.db.models import Count

countries = Pays.objects.annotate(num_emails=Count('paysOrigine'))

#example result
print(countries[0].num_emails)
```

Alternatively if you don't need counts for all at once you could add a property to the Pays model:

```
class Pays(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def email_count(self):
        return self.paysOrigine_set.all().count()
```